# Quelle est la différence entre « pour » et « contre » dans « un médicament pour/contre » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, prépositions

Ces expressions sont-elles correctes :

- *C'est le médicament contre la maladie.*
- *C'est le médicament pour la maladie.*

On dit aussi « traité pour la maladie » ou « traitement pour la maladie », mais dit-on « traité contre la maladie » ?

Comment: a mon avis, j'aurais dit, " pour ta sante" et " contre ta maladie " mais, ca c'est moi

Answer (score 9):

Les deux ont le même sens. Comme il est implicite qu'un médicament soigne, « un médicament *pour* » la maladie est équivalent à « un médicament *pour soigner* la maladie ». Donc dans ce cas particulier *pour* et *contre* ont le même sens.

Par contre, même si « traité contre la maladie » est compréhensible, il ne me paraît pas naturel, ou en tout cas moins courant que « traité *pour* ».

Comment: J'ai appris le français en France métropolitaine et je n'ai jamais entendu *traité pour la maladie*. C'est juste une remarque, ça n'en fait une règle...

Comment: @hadinbe Tu dis « traité pour un cancer du poumon » ou « traité contre un cancer du poumon » ?

Comment: c'est vrai qu'avec *cancer*, je dirais plus naturellement *traité pour* (*traité contre* sonne même très bizarre), même si je maintiens que ce n'est pas entièrement correct, à mon avis.

Answer (score 7):

Personnellement, j'aurais tendance à toujours utiliser *contre*, et je serais parfaitement capable, si quelqu'un me dit prendre un *médicament pour la grippe*, de lui demander pourquoi il veut renforcer sa grippe.

Mais c'est un avis personnel, et comme les autres réponses le montrent clairement, la version avec *pour* est assez commune. Je pense qu'il faut d'ailleurs tenir compte de l'aspect psychologique: *contre* étant négatif, ne renforce pas l'effet de guérison escompté. Pour reprendre [l'exemple de cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6010/102), les gens préfèrent, même inconsciemment, prendre un médicament pour aller mieux qu'un médicament pour combattre le mal.

Une autre explication qui me vient est qu'il existe un cas qui est correct: quand l'objet n'est pas la maladie, mais la partie du corps traitée. On va prendre un *médicament pour la gorge*, jamais un *médicament contre la gorge*. À mon sens, il est possible que ces usages corrects se soient propagés aux cas des maladies, alors qu'ils y sont incorrects.

Je reste persuadé qu'un *médicament pour la grippe* n'a aucun sens, de même qu'une assurance pour le vol ou un diffuseur pour les moustiques.

Answer (score 6):

Dans les deux cas, il y a une ellipse :

> un médicament (pour lutter) contre l'asthme

ou bien

> un médicament pour (lutter contre) l'asthme
>
> un médicament pour (soigner) l'asthme

Personnellement j'ai entendu employé les deux, indifférement.

Answer (score 4):

On traite une fièvre, on lutte contre le cancer, on se soigne pour guérir.

Le *pour* ou *contre* est ciblé pour des infections particulières, il prend son sens avec le verbe auquel il est relié. Il n'y a pas de *médicament pour ou contre la maladie*, puisqu'aucun médicament ne peut résoudre tous les problèmes médicaux.
C'est aussi la fonction du médicament lui-même qui induit le sens  *pour/contre* :

- On prend des vitamines pour aller mieux (renforcement de la vitalité)
- On prend des antibiotiques contre des bactéries (réponse à une agression externe).

Comment: On dit bien "du sirop pour la toux" non ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat -- Certes, mais c'est un raccourci : "un sirop pour *combattre* la toux".

Comment: C'est quand même dans le langage courant, c'est pour ça qu'OP a posé la question j'imagine.

Answer (score 3):

Selon moi, seules les deux formes avec *contre* sont correctes :

1. *Médicament contre la maladie*
2. *Traité/traitement contre la maladie*

L'expression *un médicament pour soigner la maladie* est une construction grammaticale complètement différente : on ne peut y utiliser *contre*.

Cependant, on peut souvent entendre *médicament pour la fièvre* d'une personne qui sous-entend *pour combattre/guérir/soigner la fièvre*. Mais ce n'est pas correct tout seul, à mon avis.